# WebSocketPayloadException with Tornado and websocket python connection

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

What does this mean when sending compressed/binary data from Tornado back to client over a websocket?

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 380, in extract
    raise WebSocketPayloadException("cannot decode: " + repr(frame.data))
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketPayloadException: cannot decode: "x\x9c\xc5\xcd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means set the binary=True option in your [self.write_message()](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/websocket.html#output) call